# Get controller from angular scope

Tags: angularjs

I have directive structure like this

```
Parent
 |-----Wrapper---|
                 |----Direct 1
                 |----Direct 2
                 |----Direct 3
                 |----Direct 4
```

I want to access some value that `Directive 3` has. My plan was to use the shared scope on `Parent` and then traverse child like this -

```
.directive('readerDirective',['$timeout',function($timeout){
         return {
           restrict : 'A',
           link:function(scope, elm, attrs){
             var elemDire = elm.find('[Direct3]');

             var direScope = angular.element(elemDire).scope();

             direScope.$watch('value',function(){
               console.log(direScope.value);
             });
           }
         };
       }])
```

But I am unable to get beyond the `Wrapper`. I can access `Wrapper` scope but cant access child directives.

I want to access `Direct 3`'s controller. Is it possible ?

I have no control over the `Wrapper` and its child as its an extrenal angular plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find out the issue. Sorry for answering my own question but it might help someone.

DOM was rendering after my `readerDirective` got executed. With this I wasn't able to find the element.

The solution was to use

```
$timeout(function(){
},0)
```

Something like this worked :

```
.directive('readerDirective',['$timeout',function($timeout){
         return {
           restrict : 'A',
           link:function(scope, elm, attrs){

         $timeout(function(){
            var elemDire = elm.find('[Direct3]');

            var direScope = angular.element(elemDire).scope();

            direScope.$watch('value',function(){
               console.log(direScope.value);
            });
         },0);

       }
     };
   }])
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it highly unlikely that you can't modify/overwrite `Wrapper` but have you considered just using `$rootScope` to share your values?

Alternatively if you can find the DOM element you can lookup the scope via 
`angular.element(ELEMENT_SELECTOR).scope()`

Comment: I don't want to modify the external plug-in to get my changes wiped on bower update. I have tried accessing child directives by using `find()` but it always works for `wrapper` but beyond that it doesn't works